# Weird CSS bug in profile reputation tab

Tags: bug, design

When I move the cursor over the left sub-tabs in my reputation tab of the profile page, there's a strange flickering, I suppose due to some JavaScript race condition or similar. I guess an image is worth 1,000 words so here goes.

[image: flickering]